# These edits cleaning up the language, shouldn't have been rejected

Tags: discussion, editing

https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92128
https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92129

I made these edits to highly upvoted question regarding toilets, that in my view, clearly makes the language more professional and readable.

Is it necessary that travel SE questions carry this tone of adult embarrassment when it comes to talk about toilets?

Answer (score 5):

You may have noticed the meme in the question, where we have a whole series of questions with this title, affectionately known as the Bathroom 101 series, in some of the [chat] circles.

Some might argue that you're disagreeing with the original author's intent, and also, edits must improve the question - simply rewording might be construed as not adding any benefit.

I'm not one of those who voted, but I am aware of the community's affinity for these posts, so wouldn't be surprised if that's the reason. Looking forward to hearing from the voters tho.

Answer (score 3):

Toilets are an awkward topic, and the tone of language of the original answer is slightly on the tongue-in-cheek side (but only slightly).  I think it's quite appropriate given the topic.